# MySql time differences, unexpected bahavior

Tags: mysql, datetime, dbvisualizer

The following behavior seems strange:

```
select time_to_sec(timediff('00:00:00', '00:00:01')); --  -1
select timediff('00:00:00', '00:00:01'); -- 00:00:01
select time_to_sec('00:00:01'); -- 1
```

According to the MySql reference timediff returns arg1 - arg2. Therefore, the result of the first statement is correct.

However, the 2nd statement returns the result of arg2 - arg1 or the absolute value of arg1 - args2. Therefore, f(g(x)) is not equal to y <- g(x), f(y) so to say. Can anyone explain?

Comment: `select timediff('00:00:00', '00:00:01');` actually returns `-00:00:01`. Your client might not be displaying the minus sign.

Comment: Works for me too, showing `-00:00:01` in HeidiSQL

Comment: I rechecked, and it's 00:00:01 again using DbVisualizer. So it must be that.